# Any way to determine what "configure" parameters were used for current installation of nginx?

Tags: nginx, installation, configuration

I want to upgrade nginx, and I want to use the same `./configure` parameters I used the last time (`--prefix=...`, `--conf=...`, etc...). If I don't have access to the original installation directory, is there any way to query nginx or any config/cache file that I could use to obtain these parameters? (If not, is there any way to determine what these parameters were if I do have access to the original installation directory?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figures that I spend half an hour researching this, can't find anything, and post a question only to find the answer five minutes later staring at me in the docs: http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine

> -V Print nginx version, compiler version and configure parameters.

So `nginx -V` did what I needed.